# Underscore.js Case Insensitive Sorting

Tags: sorting, underscore.js, case-insensitive

Having some slight issues trying to get underscore.js to do case-insensitive sorting.  I have an array of objects and would like to be able to sort by property name.

Using shortcut method [sortBy](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy)

> iteratee may also be the string name of the property to sort by (eg. length).

Array to be sorted:

```
var array = [{ name: 'test_1234', description: 'zzaaa bb cc'}, 
         { name: 'zz1111', description: 'ZAAbbbcc'}, 
         { name: 'TEST', description: '4422'}, 
         { name: '1a2929', description: 'abcdef'}, 
         { name: 'abc', description: 'Full description'}, 
         { name: 'GGGGH', description: '123456'}];
```

Sorting using this method, sortProperty = 'name', the result places uppercase before lowercase.

```
var sorted = _.sortBy(array, sortProperty);

1a2929 - abcdef
GGGGH - 123456
TEST - 4422
abc - Full description
test_1234 - zzaaa bb cc
zz1111 - ZAAbbbcc
```

I assume this has to do with case sensitivity, but I can't figure out how to change names in the array to lowercase and compare that way.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:
As pointed out, you pass in name or a function, so just adjusted function to return which field to sort by:
http://jsfiddle.net/rjaqp1vg/5/

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The name to sort by can be the field name OR a function, so pass a function that does a lower-case conversion.

```
var sorted = _.sortBy(array, function (i) { return i.name.toLowerCase(); });
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I figured as much, thanks.  I just need to include what property to sort on, ie. return i.name.toLowerCase() or return i.description.toLowerCase()

Comment: This works great if you need to `_.uniq()` ignoring case too.

Answer (score 15):

Don't use _.sortBy for this. The correct way to sort strings alphabetically is to use localeCompare. Here's an example in pure Javascript:

```
['Z', 'A','z','á', 'V'].sort(function(a, b){
   return a.localeCompare(b, undefined /* Ignore language */, { sensitivity: 'base' }) 
});
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare.

Comment: IE11 up https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: That works as well, but what is the reason not to use _sortBy for this?

Comment: Because sortBy can't use `localCompare`, which is the correct way to compare strings. Instead, it uses the regular `<`, `>` operators for comparison.

Comment: @VincentWasteels this is no longer the case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: Kind of an incomplete example since the original requirement uses sortBy specifically to solve the problem of sorting arrays of objects, not strings, based on a specified property.

Answer (score 0):

Chris' answer worked well for me, and I made it a little shorter with an arrow function:

```
var sorted = _.sortBy(array, (i) => i.name.toLowerCase());
```