# Why does _sortBy not work with capital letters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I have one array. I need to sort that array using lodash. I used `_.sortBy` but it is not sorting capital string, why ?

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/2q9cdjug/

```
var arr = [
    { name: "pq" },
    { name: "ab" },
    { name: "QE" }  
]
var a = _.sortBy(arr, 'name');
console.log(a)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting an array of JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Underscore.js Case Insensitive Sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873635/underscore-js-case-insensitive-sorting)

Answer (score 2):

*But it is not sorting capital string why?*

Because `'a' !== 'A'`

You can use callback function, So you can sort them by converting to same cases using either `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()`

```
a = _.sortBy(arr, function (x) {
    return x.name.toLowerCase();
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hbcyby0m/)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the ascii table of characters

*edit: javascript uses utf-16, and not the table below (utf-8), but it is a good example to understand because utf-16 table is long*

[image]

a is 97 and A is 65

if you try `console.log("a" > "A") //true`
sorting strings should be in lowercase

Comment: The theory is correct but JavaScript uses the [UTF-16](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) encoding of the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set.

Comment: @TomBlodget that explains so much other things to me, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad. The same applies to Java, .NET, HTML, XML, ….