# Sort array ascending order using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I need to sort an array in ascending order using underscore.js. Its almost working for me but issues when 
sorting name contains CAPITAL letters, the capital letters name coming first in sorting order. Could you help me to fix this. Tahank you.

**Tried following**

```
connectors = [
    {
    "name": "ajax"
    },
    {
    "name": "jquery"
    },
    {
    "name": "FGJDE"
    }
]
sorted = _.sortBy(connectors, 'name');
```

**Expected output**

```
connectors = [
    {
    "name": "ajax"
    },
    {
    "name": "FGJDE"
    },
    {
    "name": "jquery"
    }
]
```

**Am getting wrong sorting like following**

```
connectors = [
    {
    "name": "FGJDE"
    },
    {
    "name": "ajax"
    },
    {
    "name": "jquery"
    }
]
```

Comment: Have a look at this question about [case insensitive sorting in underscore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873635/underscore-js-case-insensitive-sorting).

Comment: `_.sortBy(connectors, o => o.name.toLowerCase());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
connectors = [{
  "name": "ajax"
}, {
  "name": "jquery"
}, {
  "name": "FGJDE"
}]
sorted = _.sortBy(connectors, function (text) { return text.name.toLowerCase(); });
console.log(sorted);
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AK_Spikey/rjaqp1vg/22/)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) for it?

```js
var connectors = [{ "name": "ajax" }, { "name": "jquery" }, { "name": "FGJDE" }];

connectors.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
});

console.log(connectors);
```