# Lodash sortBy multiple keys not working as expected

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I want to sort an object array with using multiple keys. Please find the working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hkcjunyw/1/).

```
var temp = _.sortBy(array, ['Chemical', 'LocName']);
```

in the sorted array `Tetrachloroethene` appears before `cis-1,2-Dichloroethene`, why its sorting T before c and how can I correct it.

Comment: "*why its sorting T before c*" `"T".charCodeAt(0) //84` while `"c".charCodeAt(0) //99`. What order do you expect? Lowercase letters before uppercase? Case-insensitive?

Comment: This will work [Underscore.js Case Insensitive Sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873635/underscore-js-case-insensitive-sorting)